# Is there any way to integrate cloudkit in a swift package more specifically in a vapor server package?

Tags: swift, cloudkit, vapor

I was trying to build an api based on vapor 4 server and cloudKit. For that I need to connect the vapor 4 package with the cloudkit. Is there any way to connect cloudkit in a swift package?

Integrate cloudKit into a swift package.

Comment: Are you targeting macOS exclusively? Or other desktop platforms as well? [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit) is only available on Apple platforms, but it is a system framework, so you don't need to add an extra dependency for it, you can simply call it from your code.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://github.com/brightdigit/MistKit - it should do what you need